# Compiling with virtual machine

Tags: c++, virtual-machine, virtualbox

If I compiled some C++ code on a virtual machine running on my Windows machine, could I compile for other platforms? Would compiling C++ code on my virtual machine with Mac OS installed (with a compiler for Mac) give me a working file that can actually run on a Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two part answer: **yes**, ***but*** you can't *legally* install Mac OS on a Virtual Machine. However, a cross-compiler is one that will compile on one architecture and produce code that runs on another. And that is **legal** (and somewhat common, for embedded architectures).

Comment: I don't think that would work for my case. I want to use Qt Creator to deploy for IOS. Right now I can deploy my Qt projects on Windows and Android. But, to deploy on IOS I need a Mac. Which is why I want to install Mac OS on a virtual machine and on that install Qt Creator. I'm pretty sure Qt documents say you need a Mac.

Comment: @6EQUJ5 I *understand*, if you bought a mac you could compile for IOS. You can **then** install Windows (only the **full retail** edition) in a Virtual Machine (on the Mac) and compile it for Windows (and then run that on Windows). This is what the respective **licenses** allow (and not a technical limitation). There **are** [cross compilers](https://github.com/waneck/linux-ios-toolchain) for *linux* to *ios* (I'm not certain how complete they are).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I guess I have to accept that I won't be deploying Qt applications to IOS as of now. Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your question has absolutely nothing to do with virtual machines.

You are essentially asking whether C++ is a portable language.

The answer is that yes, C++ is a portable language, provided that you are careful enough to only use standard features and avoid using external libraries which may only work on specific operating systems.

Note that C++ is a portable language, executables produced by compiling C++ generally aren't.  So, you will need to recompile on each system that you want to target.

Comment: If you read my question, I asked if I could produce executables for different systems by recompiling on a **virtual machine** that has a different system installed.

Comment: It should not matter if you compile under a virtual machine or real hardware  running the os you want to target.

Comment: @drescherjm So, if I wanted to produce an executable from C++ code (portable) that runs on Mac, I could install Mac OS on my virtual machine on my Windows machine, and compile the code with the appropriate compiler? All on the Mac OS running on the virtual machine?